# How to get an element by data attribute when there are multiple values for the same attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

How to get an element by data attribute when there are multiple values for the same attribute ?

```
<a data-multiplevalues="valuea valueb valuec">Test</a>

$("a[data-multiplevalues='valuea valueb valuec']") - works

$("a[data-multiplevalues='valuea']") - doesn't work
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `[data-multiplevalues='valuea']` the attribute has to be exactly equal to the value, if you want to select an element with an attribute that contains white space separed values you can use

```
a[data-multiplevalues~='valuea']
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors for more

Comment: looks like `~` is a bit more strict, but exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 1):

You are using attribute equality selector so you need exact match. You can use `*` to get the elements that contains the string in given attribute value. If the string you are looking in expected in the start then you can use starts with selector using `^` instead of using `*` You can read more about the wild card selector [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
$("a[data-multiplevalues*='valuea']")
```